# Name of obstetric device used to suck milk out of a mother's breast

Tags: word-request

I would like to know what the name of the obstetric device used to suck breast milk out of a mother's breast into a bottle so that it can later be administered to the infant at a later time when the mother is not present is called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for a **[breast pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breast_pump)**.

The term is used for all kinds, from the simple manual type with a lever to complicated electrical devices.